# Select statement that that counts total number of distinct entries in one table, depending on data from another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables: DATA and USERS

USERS

```
id       sqft       postal       province       city
==========================================================
1          1          Y7R          BC          Vancouver
2          2          Y7R          BC          Vancouver
3          1          L5B          ON          Toronto
```

and

DATA

```
id     uid     power
=======================
1       1       1000
2       2       1300
3       1       1500
```

uid in table DATA matches to id in table USERS

I want to be able to count the the number of distinct uid in DATA where the `postal code` is *Y7R* and `sqft` is *1*

Comment: FYI this isn't a php question, your tags are wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
   FROM `DATA` AS `d` 
   INNER JOIN `USERS` AS `u` 
   ON u.id=d.uid 
   WHERE u.postal='Y7R' AND u.sqft=1 
   GROUP BY u.id;
```

They should be distinct anyway if you have a proper schema, if so just remove the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D.UID) FROM DATA D 
LEFT JOIN USERS U ON D.UID=U.ID 
WHERE U.POSTAL='Y7R' AND U.SQFT=1)
```

In case you need distinct

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
FROM   USERS a
JOIN   DATA b ON a.id = b.uid
WHERE  a.sqft = 1 AND
       a.postal = 'Y7R'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
  FROM   USERS a
            INNER JOIN  DATA b 
                ON a.id = b.uid
 WHERE  a.sqft = 1 AND
        a.postal = 'Y7R'
```

Comment: I think the problem im having is that the the row im trying to count is the same row im using to compare the two tables